# How to define self-defined log in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am now dealing with a huge table that contains XML each row.

My job is to write *sp* to parse the `XML` and insert its data to the other corresponding tables row by row.

But there is a problem that when the *sp* interrupts, partial data is inserted into the new table while the others are not.

So, I need to delete the dirty data to recover.

Normally the solution is to use `transaction`, right?

But it really slows down the whole process to an unacceptable level.

My thought is that, when handling a new row of XML, its Id is output to a log.

If the *sp* breaks down and restarts, it checks the log, finds the last Id, and check if the Id is completed(there is a flag column).

If not, it will delete all the info of that row, and begin handling the row again.

So my question is that, in SQL server, is there any way in **SQL Server** to implement the `log` function, or is there any other solution that can help me realize my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add new column (temporary) in your table to check if row is migrated. For example:

```
ALTER TABLE ....
ADD IsMigrated BIT;
```

Then in your transaction block:

```
SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    -- CODE BLOCK GOES HERE
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
   
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
  
   IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
   BEGIN
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   END;

   -- GET ERRORS DETAILS OR THROW ERROR
   
END CATCH;

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT OFF;
```

you can select only 50-100-500 rows from your original table. Then, migrate the data. Finally, update there `IsMigrated` flag.

You can `SELECT` the rows like the following:

```
SELECT TOP(500) ID
INTO #records_to_migrated
FROM [original_table]

-- migrate the data

UPDATE [original_table]
SET [IsMigrated] = 1
FROM [original_table] A
INNER JOIN #records_to_migrated B
    ON A.[ID] = B.[ID];
```

Of course the whole thing can be in loop and you can use `WAITFORDELAY` in order to ensure other processes are able to do some work.

Also, if the original table is changed, you can add a trigger to reset the `IsMigrated` flag.

Comment: Yep, that's a better option than what I had in mind. Followed the XY lead of the OP :-)

Comment: Out of curiosity, would you add the cursor / loop / insert in between the `begin transaction` and `commit transaction` @gotqn?

Comment: @Birel No, the `LOOP` will be outer for the transaction - the idea is, loop and commit, if there is an error, rollback only the last loop iteration. Then, restart it.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks @gotqn